# Monitor Windows Sound Volume indicator in Java

Tags: java

How do I monitor the indicator and get the decibel value?

Comment: You are looking for code for a VU meter.  Also if you are looking for decibels, as in sound pressure level, that isn't possible.  At least, it isn't possible without some reference and calibration.  You can however get dB as in signal where 0dB is maximum.

Comment: you mean it is not possible from Windows Master source?

Comment: I think your answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727511/java-sound-api-to-access-the-system-master-volume-control-in-vista-and-win-7