# Change Windows Master Volume Java

Tags: java, windows, keyevent

im actually trying to figure out how i can set the System Master Volume in Windows 7/Vista.

Using javax.sound wont work cause of the new line system of Windows.
So i got 2 other options but dont know how to do this.

First option is sending a Media Key like "VK_VOLUME_UP", but the Media Keys arent listed as `KeyEvent` in java.awt.KeyEvent. Is it possible to add an new key?

Second but worst option is using and command line tool written in another language to set System Volume, but i dont like this option.

Comment: There are *no* such key that can increase the volume on *my* keyboard!

Comment: they exist ^^ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Sound API to access the system/master volume control in Vista and Win 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727511/java-sound-api-to-access-the-system-master-volume-control-in-vista-and-win-7)

Comment: turning my app in xp compatibility mode isnt an option for me, so its not duplicated question

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249550/is-there-a-way-in-java-jna-to-set-the-master-system-volume-reliably-in-xpv/3262107

Answer (score 0):

Download this standalone app:
http://www.desktopapps.co.uk/audioApp.php
Then start the program with the volup parameter.